# Oracle DBMS_Scheduler RUN DBMS_JOB on 9:10AM and 11:30 AM Daily

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks, dbms-scheduler

I want to schedule a job which should run 09:10AM and 11:45AM on every Saturday.

I am trying to create a job `dbms_scheduler.create_job` with following interval

```
,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=THU; BYHOUR=9,11; BYMINUTE=10,45; BYSECOND=0'
```

but looks like its creating 4 jobs which will run every Thursday at 9 and 11 hours on 30 and 45 minutes.

Is there any way to create the job interval which will run the job on 9:10 and 11:45 on every Saturday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two schedules.

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_schedule (
    schedule_name   => 'SCHEDULE_9', 
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=SAT; BYHOUR=9;  BYMINUTE=10; BYSECOND=00;');
  dbms_scheduler.create_schedule (
    schedule_name   => 'SCHEDULE_11', 
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=SAT; BYHOUR=11; BYMINUTE=45; BYSECOND=00;'); 
  dbms_scheduler.create_job (
    job_name        => 'MY_JOB',
    job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action      => 'MY_PROCEDURE',
    start_date      => systimestamp,
    repeat_interval => 'SCHEDULE_9,SCHEDULE_11',
    end_date        => NULL,
    enabled         => TRUE,
    comments        => 'Job that runs at 09:10 and 11:45 every Saturday ');
END;
/
```

Comment: Yeap,, correct,, i thought maybe there was any other option other than creating 2 diff. schedules,,, but looks like that's the only option... thanks